# Unable to set Python Kivy UI for different device platforms

Tags: python, android, kivy

I am trying to develop a simple application. Here are the details.

First screen shows a simple message and start button.
Second screen taken two text inputs and submit button to send data to Python function and process data.
Third screen takes the response and show on the screen with a return button.

Here is my sample kv file. When i run the application on Desktop platform UI looks fine. But when i package the same application into .apk and run on android device its UI does not show perfectly.

```
#:kivy 1.11.1
#:import hex kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex
<MyBoxLayout@BoxLayout>:
  orientation: 'vertical'
  padding: 100
  #padding: [50, 0, 50, 0]
  size: root.size
  pos: root.pos

<Manager>:
  result: "msg"
  percentage: "per"
  size: root.size
  pos: root.pos
  canvas:
    Color:
      #rgba: 0, 0, 1, 1    # Green
      rgba: hex('#9B1B30')
    Rectangle:
      pos: self.pos
      size: self.size
      source: 'seaside-forest.jpg'

  Screen:
    name: 'start'
    MyBoxLayout:
      Label:
        text: "Relationships are precious. It may be between anyone. Please hold them tight and respect each other."
        font_size: 32
        valign: "middle"
        #size: self.texture_size
        text_size: self.size
        color: hex('#FFFFFF')
      Button:
        text: "Start"
        color: hex('#FFFFFF')
        background_color: hex('#926F5B')
        size_hint: 0.5, 0.2
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.5, 'y':.2}
        font_size: 32
        #on_press: app.sm.current = 'first'
        on_press:
          root.playstart()
          app.sm.current = 'first'

  Screen:
    name: 'first'
    MyBoxLayout:
      GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        Label:
          text: "First Name"
          bold: True
          font_size: 32
          color: hex('#FFFFFF')
        ValidateInput:
          id: firstname
          multiline: False
          text: ""
          hint_text: "Insert alphabets only"
          on_text:
            self.readonly = True if len(self.text.strip()) == 15 else False
          font_size: 32
        Label:
          text: "Second Name"
          bold: True
          color: hex('#FFFFFF')
          font_size: 32
        ValidateInput:
          id: secondname
          multiline: False
          text: ""
          hint_text: "Insert Alphabets only"
          on_text:
            self.readonly = True if len(self.text.strip()) == 15 else False
          font_size: 32
      Button:
        text: "Submit"
        color: hex('#FFFFFF')
        background_color: hex('#926F5B')
        size_hint: 0.5, 0.2
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.5, 'y':.2}
        font_size: 32
        #on_press: root.results()
        #on_release: app.sm.current = 'other'
        on_press:
          root.results()
          app.sm.current = 'other'

  Screen:
    name: 'other'
    MyBoxLayout:
      GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        Label:
          text: "Your Compatibility"
          underline: True
          bold: True
          color: hex('#FFFFFF')
          font_size: 32
        Label:
          id: per
          text: str(root.percentage) + '%'
          font_size: 32
          #text: "%"
        Label:
          text: "Advice"
          underline: True
          bold: True
          color: hex('#FFFFFF')
          font_size: 32
        Label:
          id: msg
          font_size: 32
          text: str(root.result)
          #text: "msg"
      Button:
        text:'Return'
        color: hex('#FFFFFF')
        background_color: hex('#926F5B')
        font_size: 32
        size_hint: 0.5, 0.2
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.5, 'y':.2}
        on_press:
          #root.playreturn()
          app.sm.current = 'first'
```

Kindly help me with suggestion or modification to my kv file such that it will be compatible with all the devices

Please find my screen shots from desktop and Android device. From Desktop application ui looks fine but in Android device it is very small sized.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The gui presumably does what you have coded it to do. Could you explain more how you want it to be different but can't work out how to achieve?

Comment: @inclement i have attached the first screen from both desktop and android device. The desktop ui looks fine but when the same app i launch in android device the font size show very small in size. When i try to edit the font size to make the UI look fine on android the desktop ui is getting disturbed. Is there anyway i can change my kv file such that it shows fine in both desktop and android devices